# Spring deferredResult performance issue with Okhttp

Tags: spring, performance, spring-mvc, okhttp, deferred

I'm trying to test a basic blocking and non-blocking API controller that stream `OkHttp` response like following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HttpProxyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HttpProxyServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/test")
    public static class TestController {
        private static final String URL = ...;

        @Autowired
        private OkHttpClient client;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "blocking")
        public void blocking(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL)
                    .build();
            try (ResponseBody body = client.newCall(request).execute().body()) {
                StreamUtils.copy(body.byteStream(), httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
            }
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "non-blocking")
        public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> nonBlocking() {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL)
                    .build();

            DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    ResponseEntity<Void> responseEntity =
                            new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
                    deferredResult.setResult(responseEntity);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> responseEntity =
                            new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(response.body().byteStream()),
                                                 HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
                    deferredResult.setResult(responseEntity);
                }
            });
            return deferredResult;
        }
    }
}
```

**Important thing**: I want to stream result ! I don't want to save whole result in memory. That's why for non-blocking I created a `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>`.

However using basic JMeter script that crawls on both API, the non-blocking is really slower than the blocking one

- 500 threads

Blocking result:

[image]

Non-blocking result:

[image]

There is any reason?

---

Update 1:

New test

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "non-blocking-2")
public DeferredResult<InputStreamResource> nonBlockingBlocking() throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL)
            .build();

    DeferredResult<InputStreamResource> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    deferredResult.setResult(new InputStreamResource(client.newCall(request).execute().body().byteStream()));
    return deferredResult;
}
```

As similar result as *full blocking*. So I don't think is performance issue directly come from `DeferredResult`.

Comment: Well of course the latter will have the same time, as yu are executing the call syncronous and that basically disables the effect of `DeferredResult`. You will have to execute the client call on a different thread, if you don't do that it still operates syncronous.

Comment: Note that although OkHttp has an asynchronous API, its implementation currently uses one thread per request.